# Differentiation to Find slope if tangent line Implicitly

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have the equation $x^3+y^3-4xy=8$. I need to find the equation for the tangent line at $(2,0)$. When I derived the equation I came up with $$y'=\frac{3x^2-4x}{-3y^2-4y}$$

Obviously, if you plug in $x=2$ and $y=0$, your answer will be undefined. I think I differentiated improperly, can someone point out my mistake and enlighten me to the steps of proper differentiation for this equation?

Comment: If you show your differentiation computation, it's easier to point out the mistake.You should be getting $y'(x)=\dfrac{4y(x)-3x^2}{3(y(x))^2-4x}$ according to my calculations.

Comment: thank you! I looked back on it and noticed my mistake. I appreciate you help.

Comment: You're welcome. It is unlikely that someone will answer this question now, so I suggest you answer yourself so the question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the derivative is taken properly you should get $y'=(4y-3x^2)/(3y^2-4x)$. Expanded it would be $3x^2+3y^2*y'-4xy'+4y=0$. By isolating the $y'$ and you get $y'(3y^2-4x)=4y-3x^2$. Divide both sides by $3y^2-4x$ and you get the proper derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit differentiation method to find $y'$
$$x^3+y^3-4xy=8$$ 
$$3x^2+3y^2y'-4(y+xy')=0$$
$$3x^2+3y^2y'-4y-4xy'=0$$
$$y'(3y^2-4x)=4y-3x^2$$
$$y'=\frac{4y-3x^2}{3y^2-4x}$$
Plug in $x=2$ and $y=0$.
$$y'=\frac{-12}{-8}=\frac{3}{2}=k$$
Let's find $l$.
$$y=kx+l$$
$$0=3+l \to l=-3$$
Tangent line is: $y=\frac{3}{2}x-3$